# RemainAfterExit not working

Tags: systemd, initrd, systemd-unit

I have a systemd service unit, for which I want to enable `RemainAfterExit`. This runs in a custom intrd. Here is my unit:

```
[Unit]
Description=Ask for network config
Conflicts=initrd-switch-root.target
Before=initrd-switch-root.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ask_network_config
StandardInput=tty-force
StandardOutput=inherit
```

You can see that I have enabled `RemainAfterExit`, and `Type` is `oneshot`. However once the script has successfully completed, the unit is not active:

```
initrd:~# systemctl status ask_network_config
● ask_network_config.service - Ask for network config
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ask_network_config.service; enabled-runtime; vendor preset: >
     Active: inactive (dead) since Tue 2022-04-12 07:27:03 UTC; 1min 4s ago
    Process: 140 ExecStart=/usr/bin/ask_network_config (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 140 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Apr 12 07:21:55 localhost systemd[1]: Starting Ask for network config...
Apr 12 07:21:58 localhost imager[175]: Asking for network config.
Apr 12 07:26:56 localhost imager[194]: Configuring network
Apr 12 07:26:56 localhost systemd[1]: Finished Ask for network config.
Apr 12 07:27:03 localhost systemd[1]: ask_network_config.service: Succeeded.
Apr 12 07:27:03 localhost systemd[1]: Stopped Ask for network config.
initrd:~# Shared connection to 192.168.76.5 closed.
```

How do I fix this, so that it shows as active after it successfully completes?

Comment: Did you by any means pull in the `initrd-switch-root.target` ? if you did, I'd say that `systemd` stopped your service due to the `Conflicts` setting.

Comment: @LL3 No, but you helped me figure out what was wrong. – ask_network_config was WantedBy initrd.target, which when one of the other services fails, then it stops all services.

I was able to solve the issue by changing the WantedBy to network.target

Please put an answer up so I can award you the bounty. You helped me find the issue.

Comment: if you find your answer. You should explain it and post it so others might find some clue to have such issue.